# Как можно удалить ячейку в таблице по нажатию на кнопку, а не свайпу

Tags: xcode, swift3

Кнопка сделана виде **radiobutton**.

Вот так выглядит **Main.Storyboard** 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так выглядит **TaskTableVC**

```
class TaskTableVC: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var addProductButton: UIButton!

    var test : [String] = ["Product_name_1", "Product_name_2", "Product_name_3", "Product_name_4", "Product_name_5"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addProductButton.setTitleColor(.textColor, for: .normal)

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return test.count
    }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ParamentrsTableViewCell

        cell.nameProduct.text = test[indexPath.row]

        return cell
        }

    @IBAction func radioButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        //Кнопка, по нажатию на ее должна удаляться ячейка
    }
}
```

Вот так выглядит **ParamentrsTableViewCell**

```
class ParamentrsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var radioButton : UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameProduct : UILabel!

}
```

Comment: непонятно, по нажатию на какую кнопку?. Вы можете всю таблицу перевести в edit состояние, тогда у всех ячеек появятся кнопки удалить

Comment: Я написал на какую кнопку "Кнопка сделана виде radiobutton."

Comment: ну так там написано  "//Кнопка, по нажатию на ее должна удаляться ячейка", а кнопка в контроллере, не в ячейке, по нажатию кнопки как контроллер узнает, какую именно ячейку надо удалять?

Comment: Почему кнопка не в ячейке, она в ячейке. Вот она: https://monosnap.com/file/PuhgT0nIDsDluGytIOHMw7ZNCgO4sH

Comment: тогда почему метод кнопки находится в TaskTableVC? так вообще не будет работать, не зависимо от того, что вы хотите запустить нажатием на кнопку. Метод кнопки должен быть в классе ячейки, и оттуда вы можете передавать сообщение делегату ячейки (в вашем случае это TaskTableVC), что надо удалить ячейку. В этом методе вы можете передать саму ячейку как параметр, а в делегате (TaskTableVC) получить её IndexPath и удалить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func myButtonMethod(sender : UIButton!) {
   self.dataSource.removeAtIndex(myIndex) // dataSource Начало массива

   self.tableview!.reloadData()

//так
//self.tableView!.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forItem: myIndex, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: nil)
}
```

Можно добавить метод

```
 self.myButton.addTarget(self, action: "myButtonMethod:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: так удалять не кошерно, надо анимацию добавить, и перезагружать только удаляемую ячейку, а не всю таблицу, похоже как  в закоментированном методе

Comment: self.tableView.beginUpdates()
удаление и 
self.tableView.endUpdates()

Comment: верно, и в главном потоке конечно же

Comment: Ну это естественно ! просто многие даже и не хотят вникать в задачу что уж говорить о том что всего лишь прочитать методы их реализации